# How do I iterate over a LinkedHashMap and select between the key and value separately?

Tags: java, iterator, hashmap, key

At the moment I have this:

```
try{
            // Create file 
            FileWriter fstream = new FileWriter("output");
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(fstream);
            Iterator mapIt = assignments.entrySet().iterator();
            while (mapIt.hasNext()){
                out.write(mapIt.next().toString()+";\n");
            }
            //Close the output stream
            out.close();
        }
```

The thing is, I can't just take the toString() of iterator, I need to take out the key and the value separately so I can put some stuff between them in the outputfile. Does anyone know how I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I iterate over each Entry in a Collection Map?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-collection-map)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will notice the iterator returns a [Map.Entry](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html) which has `getKey` and `getValue` methods.

Use those to get the respective items....something like

```
while (mapIt.hasNext()){
   Map.Entry entry = mapIt.next();
   Object key = entry.getKey();
   Object value = entry.getValue();
   // format away..
}
```

Note I put `Object` as the types of key and val, but you should specify the types according to however you defined the Map.

Comment: (Hint: generics will make this much less of a pain, and much more self-evident.)

Answer (score 1):

Since the iterator returns a set of Map.Entry, you can get the key and value separately out of that:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html

Answer (score 1):

From [How to efficiently iterate over each Entry in a Map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-do-i-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-collection-map)

```
for (Map.Entry<String, String> entry : map.entrySet())
{
    System.out.println(entry.getKey() + "/" + entry.getValue());
}
```